# adding data to a nested list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, nested-lists

any help would be appreciated! I'm scraping multiple URLs and iterating over the URLs with a for loop. I'm putting relevant data into individual lists. however, I'm trying to organize my data in a list of lists to compare with other data... that I have't scraped yet. How do I iterate through the list of lists and put data into each element of the list? this doesn't seem that hard...  don't know what I'm missing?

```
def get_info(item_urls)#, count): #count is being passed in, leaving this here for context
    for item in item_urls:
        #get data and stuff from current URL

        data = ["beer", "is", "awesome!", "...", "for", "helping", "with", "my", "depression"]
        count = len(data) # counting data for a number, that I should have just made up :)
        table = [[] for i in range(0, count)]
        for truth in data:
            for i in range(0, count):
                list('table[{}]'.format(i)).append(truth)
                print(truth)
        for thing in table[0]:
            print(thing)
   return "borked"
```

my fake logic:
for each element in data, append the element to table.

Once I iterate through all the URLs, I would like to return the entire built out table.

Answer (score 0):

`myList[i]` iterates through a list. `myList[i][j]` iterates through elements in list of lists. `j` is the index for element in the inner list.

Comment: thank you for responding but I'm still confused.'table = [[] for i in range(0, count)]
for truth in data:
    print(truth)
    for j in range(0, count):
        list(table[i][j].append(truth))
        print(truth)'

Comment: I don't understand how to format code in comments. i'm sorry